# changing spinners value based on other spinners from mysql database (Android)

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-spinner

Can someone point me to any tutorials or guides on this. how to update the value of one spinner based on the selection of the previous spinner. the data values are coming from mysql database. i have searched around but have not found any satisfactory answer. pls help.

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnersportcentername);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerListener);
```

from the above i have 2 spinners. right now im getting the data from database. and the code is below. i am getting the data. now i need to update the value of second spinner based on the item selected in the first spinner. how do i do that? i am pretty much clueless right now.

```
private void getData(){
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(FacilityConfig.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(FacilityConfig.JSON_ARRAY);

                                                    getFacility(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getFacility(JSONArray j){
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);

                            facilities.add(json.getString  (FacilityConfig.TAG_FACILITY));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FragmentOne.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, facilities));

}


private void getData2(){
    //Creating a string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(SPnameConfig.DATA_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    JSONObject j = null;
                    try {
                        //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                        j = new JSONObject(response);

                        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                        result = j.getJSONArray(SPnameConfig.JSON_ARRAY2);


                        getSpname(result);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void getSpname(JSONArray j){
    //Traversing through all the items in the json array
    for(int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
        try {
            //Getting json object
            JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);


            sportcenternames.add(json.getString(SPnameConfig.TAG_SPORTCENTERNAME));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner

    spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(FragmentOne.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, sportcenternames));
}



public class myOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Context mContext;

    public myOnItemSelectedListener(Context context){
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    private String getprice(int pos){
        String price="";
        try {
            //Getting object of given index
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(pos);

            //Fetching name from that object
            price = json.getString(FacilityConfig.TAG_PRICE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Returning the name
        return price;
    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long row) {

        switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.spinner:
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textViewPrice.setText(getprice(pos));
                break;
            case R.id.spinnersportcentername:
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "OnItemSelectedListener : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        textViewPrice.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: post relevant codes and please, list what have you already tried

Comment: This is a request for a tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    firstSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,       long id) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> newAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout
   .simple_spinner_dropdown_item, value);
    secondSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please seelct your  country",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have populate the Spinner based on other three values of Spinners. You can execute a query based on the values of other Spinners.

After populating fourth Spinner, you can set the value by using Spinner's `setSelection(index)` method.